# Python Pandas calucate Z score of groupby means

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year' : ['2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', '2010', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2011', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012', '2012'],
                   'Name' : ['Bob', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Dave', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Bill', 'Bill', 'Joe', 'Dave', 'Dave', 'Joe', 'Steve'],
                    'Score' : [95, 76, 77, 85, 82, 92, 67, 80, 77, 79, 82, 92, 64, 71, 83]})
```

I would like to get the Z Score for each *Name* in each *Year*.

I can do it if subset the Year column like this:

```
(df[df.Year == '2010'].groupby(['Year', 'Name'])['Score'].mean() - df[df.Year == '2010'].groupby(['Year', 'Name'])['Score'].mean().mean()) / ( df[df.Year == '2010'].groupby(['Year', 'Name'])['Score'].mean().std())
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `zscore` functionality in `scipy`, but be careful the default delta-degree-of-freedom is 0 in `scipy.stats.zscore`:

```
In [171]:
import scipy.stats as ss
S=(df[df.Year == '2010'].groupby(['Year', 'Name'])['Score'].mean())
pd.Series(ss.zscore(s, ddof=1), S.index)
Out[171]:
Year  Name
2010  Bill   -0.714286
      Bob     1.142857
      Joe    -0.428571
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I'm out of practice, but *shouldn't* ddof be 0 for a z-score?  I thought it was defined relative to population statistics, not sample statistics (cf. t-score).

Comment: @DSM, I think: not really. Z-score is the difference-to-mean divided by standard deviation. If we go for the default, the standard deviation that `stats.zscore` uses is of `ddof==0`, which is probably not what we want (and different from `pandas` default). To match the result from OP, `ddof=1` is necessary.

Comment: @DSM, and also, you see, to get t-score, we need to divide it further by `sqrt(N)` `N` being sample size.

Comment: Now I'm more confused-- I thought z-score and t-score were equivalent but in the z-score we use the population mean and the population s.d. and the t-score we use the sample mean and sample s.d.  (Do you have a link explaining the extra sqrt(N) factor?)  I can understand using ddof=1, but I don't think that's a Z score anymore, is it?

Comment: @DSM, Sorry for causing further confusion. To explain the difference, essentially the difference between the normal and t-distribution and their applications, would be quite involving and require a few good examples. My favorite explanation on that is section 7.9, page 169-173: http://books.google.com/books/about/Biometry.html?id=N6KCNw5NHNkC